# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\log(n)}(1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\log(n)}$ if $x>-1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

so i'm trying to study whether or not some series converges assuming some free parameter x. the series is:

(I) $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\log(n)}(1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\log(n)}$

where x is a real number such that $x>-1$

---

Let's begin by noticing that $1 \le (1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\log(n)} \le (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n \to e $ if $n \to \infty$

so if we assume $x \ge 1$ and use the nth-term divergence test we have to study:  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{\log(n)}(1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\log(n)}$

which by observation above and limit law (notice that if $x \ge 1$ both the limits exist) can be considered equivalent to  $k\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{\log(n)}$

where k is some real number $1 \le k \le e$

now notice that if $x>1$ the limit above clearly diverges, and if we assume $x=1$ it still diverges by comparison test with the harmonic series.

Indeed we have that (I) is divergent for $x \ge 1$

now assume we have $-1 < x < 1$ this time we may try using the root test.
so we have evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} |(\frac{x^n}{\log(n)})|^{\frac{1}{n}}  |(1+ \frac{1}{n})|^{\frac{\log(n)}{n}}$$

notice $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\frac{\log(n)}{n}} \to 1$

and $\lim_{n \to \infty} ({\log(n)})^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$

thus we obtain by applying again limit laws that the above limit depends just on |x|.
since by hypothesis is s.t.  $-1 < x < 1$ it means that our series has to be convergent by root test for |x|<1 and divergent for $x \ge 1$.

Am I correct? Thanks for the help

Comment: When applying the root test you have to take the absolute value of $x$. Also, the root test does not tell you if the series is convergent for $x=\pm 1$ or not.

Comment: @Gary i used the absolute value of x in the root test. i considered just the terms $|x|<1$ in the first place because i already showed  (if there is no mistake in my reasoning) that for $x \ge 1$  the series is divergent.

Comment: The absolute value should be inside the fractional power $1/n$ and not outside. You can conclude from the root test that the series diverges for $|x|>1$ and consider what happens for $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: @Gary oh you are right, didn't notice, thanks. anyway i don't understand why if the exercise ask for $x>-1$ we supposed to consider what happens when $x=-1$.

Comment: Well, in that case you just have to consider $x=1$ separately. I just said $x=-1$ because the question would make sense for all real $x$ not just $x>-1$.

Comment: @Gary got it, thank you very much